# Connecting to Hyperledger composer network using Fabric node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have created a Business Network Archive (.bna) using composer and deployed it on local fabric network, now

1.I want to connect to it using Fabric node SDK and perform the operations on it using SDK.
2.do I need to run composer-rest-server to expose the API's or I can do without it?
3.How to create users with their access to interact with the deployed fabric network from node SDK?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't mix and match like this with Composer and Fabric Node SDK.  If you are using Composer then you need to use the Composer JavaScript API, or the REST API - [this doc](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/applications/applications-index) will help you get started.
2. If you want to program using REST then yes you need to start the composer-rest-server.  But you can use the JavaScript API.
3. You can't use the Fabric Node SDK to create users for Composer.  Composer binds Participants to Identities, so you need to use the Composer REST API or JavaScript API to Issue Identities for Composer.